# Xcode keeps giving symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

Tags: xcode, architecture, symbols, arm64

Xcode keeps giving the error: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64.

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>     "_gvr_set_default_viewer_profile", referenced from:
>         _GvrCardboardHelpers_SetViewerProfile_m5325167020DC962236959852F91D9C553C51216D in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
>         _GvrCardboardHelpers_gvr_set_default_viewer_profile_m07028866FB149E1AC5CECE15964D0B9EE8A6CA97 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _GvrCardboardHelpers_gvr_set_default_viewer_profile_m07028866FB149E1AC5CECE15964D0B9EE8A6CA97)
>     "_gvr_get_time_point_now", referenced from:
>         _AndroidNativeKeyboardProvider_gvr_get_time_point_now_m06805997F8027305F0BD844EDD089F6EAC7536EB in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
>         _AndroidNativeKeyboardProvider_UpdateData_mA2A2F254C6FA0B2037353C0419FC438E985E3E01 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _AndroidNativeKeyboardProvider_gvr_get_time_point_now_m06805997F8027305F0BD844EDD089F6EAC7536EB)
>     "_gvr_reset_tracking", referenced from:
>         _GvrCardboardHelpers_Recenter_m99630154B89B72845D010213CA5A263D3969058D in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
>         _GvrCardboardHelpers_gvr_reset_tracking_m787C501547F2AF315F6CB1F8DDA59F7FCD9032AF in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _GvrCardboardHelpers_gvr_reset_tracking_m787C501547F2AF315F6CB1F8DDA59F7FCD9032AF)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

Comment: Judging by the part `AndroidNativeKeyboardProvider`, is it possible you're trying to link against an Android-specific API that iOS doesn't have? Otherwise, please create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by:

1. Installing the latest version of Unity3D and GoogleVR drivers for Unity
2. Deleting the folder Library from my Unity workspace (and Temp if you have it)
3. Deleting the folder ⁨Users⁩ ▸ ⁨{user} ▸ ⁨Library⁩ ▸ ⁨Developer⁩ ▸ Xcode
4. Then I opened Unity again and built it again as usual.

I found that solution that worked for me here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/360-video-sample-project-xcode-build-error.675871/

- Remember to have enabled "Virtual Reality Supported" and "Cardboard" added in player settings, etc. Notice I already had it enabled, but I disabled and enabled it again which seemed to import or install something! So maybe you need to disable and enable it back as well.
- Last but not least, remember to open `.xcworkspace` and **NOT** `.xcodeproj` or you will have compilation issues as the first one includes the libraries (pods) and the second one does not.